# Spring mvc:resources needs to map to the same filename?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm getting a 404 in Jetty if the mvc:resources tag in my web-context.xml is not mapped to the same filename:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/some-file" location="/WEB-INF/js/some-file.js" />
```

Where as the following works fine:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/some-file.js" location="/WEB-INF/js/some-file.js" />
```

How can I map files to a different file-name in the URL space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you don't map single files but an entire directory.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
```

As you can see the mapping attribute takes an ant path to match multiple files and directories.

For more information see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources

Comment: I need to have a specific JavaScript file at a root location: http://www.example.com/jsapi which points to a JS file brought in by WAR overlay from a Google Closure project. The filenames are long, and I need a short public alias for this.

Comment: mvc:resources is not for creating aliases. It will try map a pattern to a file and that's it. Maybe jetty can be configured to do what you want with a [RewriteHandler](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Rewrite_Handler).

Comment: the RewriteHandler did work in fact. If you can write an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you!